# What is meant by "Zero-Shot Visual Recognition"?

Tags: terminology, definitions, zero-shot-learning

Many [recent research papers](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=zero%20shot%20visual%20recognition&btnG=) contain the phrase "Zero-Shot Visual Recognition".

What exactly is meant by **zero-shot visual recognition**? Does the task need only images or also the other data like text?